# Exclude applescript files from "Export for localizations", Xcode 8.2

Tags: localization, applescript, xcode8

In my project, I included some uncompiled .applescript files I need which get compiled in build phase.
Unfortunately when I try to export for localization, Xcode (8.2) also takes these files into account and crashes with

```
myfile.applescript cannot be read in UTF-8 encoding
```

Which is obvious because it's not a textfile. Is there a way to exclude this from creating XLIFF file?

**EDIT:** creating .strings files with genstrings works though. Just can't export XLIFF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this with removing the applescript temporarily for building XLIFF file.